# How to get cyrillic symbols in json?

Tags: symfony

I use `CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER` to avoid [circular references](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references).

```
        $items = $this->entityManager->getRepository(OrderMainCategory::class)->findAll();
        $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
        $defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object) {
                return $object->getName();
            },
        ];
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
        $data = $serializer->serialize($items, 'json');
        return $this->json($data);
```

but get `{\u0022id\u0022:1,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022\\u0410\\u043b\\u043...`

I know about `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` but i don't understand how to use it in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply changes like this:

```php
return $this->json(json_decode($data))
            ->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Because after serialization the `$data` is a string. And `json()` method of  [AbstractController use](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L154) only `JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT` by default.